# Remove White space in vim, keep indentation

Tags: vim

I am looking to remove all white space in vim, but keep the default indentation as is. Currently all out files use spaces instead of tabs so:

```
content
    content inside[Sneeky white space of epicness]
content
```

Should be:

```
content
    content inside
content
```

**Note:** `[Sneeky white space of epicness]` represents a block of white space.

Comment: Indentation means the whitespace _before any_ text, so that would turn your example to `contentinside`. I guess you mean **trailing whitespace**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [substitute](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace)

```
%s/ *$//g
```

`$` means end of line.
`*` means match zero or more instances of the previous element (as suggested by [Jite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/921723/jite))

Be aware that you could have tab... To represent any white space, use `\s`

```
%s/\s*$//g
```

---

**EDIT:**

As suggested by [kojiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418413/kojiro) you could use `+` instead of `*`. With a `*`, vim does the replace on EVERY line. With a `+`, the replace is done only where it needs to be done in that case.

`+` means match at least one instance of the previous element.
With `vim` you have to escape the `+`.

See `:help pattern-overview` for more details.

My final answer :

```
%s/\s\+$//g
```

Comment: Or perhaps better explained, `*` means match zero or more instances of previous...

Comment: Right, but you don't want to replace *zero* whitespace with nothing. That would affect every line. You want `\s\s*` or `\s\+`.

Comment: I agree with kojiro, I'd replace `*` with `+` which means match atleast one or more instances of previous.

Comment: @kojiro What do you mean by zero whitespace ?

Comment: @LucM I mean `\s*$` matches *zero or more* whitespace at the end of a line. `"foo"` ends with zero whitespace, so this would match, and the substitution expression would take place, replacing the zero whitespace at the end of the line with an empty string. The line would remain unchanged, but it's an expensive operation to do nothing.

Comment: @LucM You miss a `$` ending the string in your final answer, without it it's very much wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins that can detect and (on demand, or even automatically) delete trailing whitespace. My [DeleteTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3967) is one of them, and handles way more cornercases that the simple `:%s` command usually given. (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)